# How to read file lines and store them? C++

Tags: c++, char, ifstream

So far I am able to open a `txt` file and store them as variables.

My `txt` file looks like this

`Tim, 24, Male`

I have been able to store them as variables such as `name`, `age`, `gender`

This is my code

```
ifstream inputfiles ("test.txt");
    if(!inputfiles.is_open())
    {

    }
    else
    {
        while(inputfiles >> name >> age >> gender)
        {
            cout << name << "\n";
            cout << age << "\n";
            cout << gender << "\n";
        }
```

However, my code doesn't store the values as variables when my `txt` file looks like this...

```
Tim
24
Male
```

How do I modify my code such that it can read my file line by line and store it in its variables?

Comment: It should do. It ignores whitespace which newline is part of.

Comment: Why didn't you put the if like `if(inputfiles.is_open())` and the while inside the if so you could remove the `else`?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line)

Comment: Have you *tried* it?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15089622/1769720 to tokenize simply a comma separated line

Comment: @ravi To test for `inputfiles.is_open()` is superfluous, that's already handled correctly in the `while()` loops condition.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yeah I failed to notice that... thanks for correcting me...

Comment: "However, my code doesn't store the values as variables when my txt file looks like this". [Yes it does](http://rextester.com/DHY93252)

Answer (score -1):

If I am right, You want to store it like:

1. Tim     24      Male
2. John    25      Male

Use a class

```
    class data
    {
        public:
        char name[10],gen;
        int age;
        void getdata()
        {
            cout<<"Enter Name";
            gets(name);
            cout<<Enter age";
            cin>>age;
            cout<<"enter gender";
            cin>>gen;
        }
        void putdata()//use cout statements here
        {
        //put cout statements
        }
    };
```

Now in your main function,use write functon

```
fstream f;
f.open("YourFile.txt",ios::in|ios::out);    
data r;    
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    r.getdata();
    f.write((char*)&r,sizeof(r));
}
```

Remember,always use read function to print the database values if you used write.

```
f.seekg(0,ios::beg);
while(!f.eof())
{
   f.read((char*)&r,sizeof(r));
}
```

If you want to store the text as it is without conversion...use put function.